# RefererError on iPhone only Google Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, safari

I have an issue only with iPhone for Google Maps (in Browser). I use `angular-google-maps`. I'm pretty familiar with the whole process and it is basically working on every device except the iPhone 6 (even if it works on the iPhone emulator of XCode).

I guess the problem is with the `Referer` Header: I get this one with iPhone 6:

(via Charles Proxy):

[image: iPhone]

And this one on my mac (Chrome):

[image]

My API Key have that configuration (I tried, more or less, every possible combination):
[image]

So, but still with this configuration, I got this error:

[image]

Of course, you can try [there](http://jobninja.eu:82/#/signup)

Comment: Is it working without adding any referer in the api key?, because if it does that confirms you are right. But if  doesn't maybe you can try checking other possible cause stated [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#api-key-error)

Comment: Good idea! I'll try it and come back to you! :)